# Check if variable values are close to each other

Tags: c#, math

Assume we've got two variables:

```
int test = 50;
int test1 = 45;
```

Now I want to check if `test1` is near of `test` within -5/+5 inclusive. How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you simply want to test whether the difference between the two numbers is within a certain range.

```
// Get the difference
int d = test - test1;

// Test the range
if (-5 <= d && d <= 5)
{
    // Within range.
}
else
{
    // Not within range
}
```

Answer (score 15):

```
const int absoluteDifference = 5;

int test = 50;
int test1 = 45;

if (Math.Abs(test - test1) <= absoluteDifference)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The values are within range.");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
if (Math.Abs(test - test1) <= 5)
{
    // Yay!!
}
```

This invokes the mathematical "Absolute" function which returns a positive value even if negative. Eg. Math.Abs(-5) = 5

Answer (score 2):

```
using System;
...
if (Math.Abs(test - test1) <= 5) return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to capsulate this in a function.
Unfortunately, you can't use a generic type, because this is not supported for the + operator.
So it needs to be implemented for int and any others types specifically.

```
public static bool DoesDifferenceExceed(int value, int differentValue, int maximumAllowedDiffernece)
{
    var actualDifference = Math.Abs(value - differentValue);
    return actualDifference <= maximumAllowedDiffernece;
}
```